# Is Type Cast in WPF Binding possible?

Tags: wpf

I have a Catel User Control that will be acting as my tab item.

I have a tab control with the following style:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ShellTabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <!--Display the child view name on the tab header-->
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Header}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>


    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,10,10,0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ShellTabItemStyle}">
        <views:OpsReport01ParameterView />
        <views:NonCompliantTradesParameterView />
        <views:AuditReportParameterView />
    </TabControl>
```

My UserControl implements an interface which specifies a Header property.  Is there any way to cast 'UserControl' to an interface IMyInterface?  I have tried using IMyInterface as the AncestorType but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending the `UserControl` class and adding the `Header DependencyProperty` into a new class:

```
public partial class YourUserControl : UserControl
{
    // Declare Header DependencyProperty here
}
```

Then in your other custom `UserControl`s, extend this `YourUserControl` 'base' class instead of the `UserControl` class:

```
public partial class AuditReportParameterView : YourUserControl
{
    ...
} 
// etc.
```

Then you can use `YourUserControl` as the type in your `RelativeSource Binding` for all of the derived classes:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    YourPrefix:YourUserControl}}, Path=Header}" />
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you have tried something like this before?  I am getting errors and it seems to me that dependency properties have static definitions, so wouldn't that confuse WPF with multiple subclasses inheriting the same dependency property? FYI error for me is Binding Expression path error.

Comment: Specifically:  BindingExpression path error: 'HEADER_PROPERTY' property not found on 'object' ''AuditReportParameterView'

Comment: Ok, solved one isse, I was not using the naming convention for DP properties which apperently is a big deal.  Now FindAncestor is not finding the baseclass.

Comment: It was saying it couldn't find the Property, I am trying a different approach now to see if it will work.  I'll post again if I'm forced to abandon it.